# How to set iptables for Openvpn running console with ssh income

Tags: ssh, iptables, routing, openvpn

I have a Ubuntu server, which I remotely control it via ssh, I need to run an OpenVpn client on this server, so all traffic will go through the VPN tunnel, except for two things, 1. the ssh connection from my computer here, 2. Another program uses self-defined port 43210.

This is what I have tried.
I created a new ip rule table for all the traffic that I don't want to use the VPN:

```
# reserved values
255      local 
254      main
253      default   
0        unspec
#
# local
#
#1      inr.ruhep
206      passvpn
```

I defined the behavior for the passvpn table to use the local no-VPN device:

```
ip route add default via xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dev eth0 table passvpn
```

where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is my gateway

I add a new IP rule to direct those marked traffic to the table:

```
ip rule add fwmark 66 table passvpn
```

I mark the SSH and the other program's traffic with this 66 mask, using port number:

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j MARK --set-mark 66
```

When I run the OpenVpn, my ssh connection terminated, and cannot establish any new connections, error as “timedout”. I thought maybe the connection request from my computer cannot reach the server with the VPN running, so I add another iptables rule as:

```
iptables -t mangle -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j MARK --set-mark 66
```

But still not working.

Can someone please tell me, if I did anything wrong here? Any suggestion will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Could you try to write your rules into a script and start up that script in your `route-up` VPN config?